# Flutter pageview : Find first and last page and swipe directions

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am working on a book app using flutter. I am showing book pages using pageview for every chapter.  The problem is when the user swipe left on the last page, I should load the next chapter from the database along with the chapter title. Vice-versa right swipe on the first page for the previous chapter. So how can I find that user in the first page or last page and swiping left or right?

Comment: see how `RefreshIndicator` detects boundary overscrolls (or even use it directly ?)

Comment: and, did you check `RefreshIndicator` sources? if so, did you notice how it detects overscrolls?

Comment: RefreshIndicator  using NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>.  I am using SingleChildScrollView inside page view. So in any direction I getting notified without direction information If I am using  NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>.

Comment: try other notifications then

Answer (score 12):

You can check if it's the last of first page by comparing the `onPageChanged` methods `index` with your `collection.length`, like so:

```
PageView(
  onPageChanged: (index) {
    if (index + 1 == myCollection.length) {
      loadNextChapter();
    } else if (index == 0) {
      loadPreviousChapter();
    }
  },
);
```

Edit 1:

Using GestureDetector:

```
PageView mPageView = PageView(
  onPageChanged: (index) {
    if (index + 1 == myCollection.length) {
      hasReachedEnd = true;
    } else if (index == 0) {
      hasReachedFirst = true
    } else {
      hasReachedFirst = false
      hasReachedEnd = false
    }
  },
);

GestureDetector mGestureDetector = GestureDetector(
  child: mPageView
  onHorizontalDragEnd: (dragEndDetails) {
    if (dragEndDetails.primaryVelocity < 0 && hasReachedStart) {
      loadPreviousChapter(); //if you want to go to the next page once fetched you can do so by adding .then()
    } else if (dragEndDetails.primaryVelocity > 0 && hasReachedEnd) {
      loadNextChapter();
    }
  }
);
```

Whenever we scroll left or right we check which direction we are swiping and if we are at the end or the beginning of the item list.

Whenever we scroll to a new page we check if we are at the end or at the start of the items.

Combining these will give you the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks. But how to know user swiping left or right when index is 0?

Comment: Do you really want to load the next pages after the user tried to scroll but no content existed?
Using the answer above you will load the next section of pages when the user lands on the last page, making it a seamless scrolling experience.
`onPageChanged` will not trigger in the initial state, so you wont load the previous chapter on startup.
What direction you are swiping from is (unless i misinterpreted your question) irrelevant.
You always want to load the next set of pages when the user reach the end in any direction.

Comment: If user swipe left in the last page? instead of going to next chapter?

Comment: Then the he will go back to the previous page, but the next set of pages will be loaded.
If you really don't want to load the pages before the user tries to swipe to a nonexistent page you can add a listener to the PageViewController and run your logic in there.

Another approach could be to wrap the PageView in a GestureRecognition Widget.
I'll update my answer for better formatting tools to show you what I mean.

Comment: If I add GestureDetector  for pageview, GestureDetector   called only for first page. If I add GestureDetector  for each page inside pageview, GestureDetector  called but pageview is not scrolling.

Comment: The GestureDetector is not receiving any horizontal drag events for me. Only `onHorizontalDragCancel` and `onHorizontalDragDown` are firing.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using OverscrollIndicatorNotification. With chapter and sub chapters.

```
    return new Container(
    child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
        onNotification: ((notification) {
          print(notification.toString());
          if (notification is OverscrollIndicatorNotification) {
            if (notification.depth == 0 ||_listOfCat.indexOf(_category)==0) {
              int index = _listOfSubCat.indexOf(_subCategory);
              if (notification.leading) {
                if (index != 0) {
                  setSubCatId(_listOfSubCat[index - 1]);
                } else {
                  index = _listOfCat.indexOf(_category);
                  if (index != 0) {
                    setCatId(_listOfCat[index - 1]);
                  }
                }
              } else {
                if (index != _listOfSubCat.length - 1) {
                  setSubCatId(_listOfSubCat[index + 1]);
                } else {
                  index = _listOfCat.indexOf(_category);
                  if (index != _listOfCat.length - 1) {
                    setCatId(_listOfCat[index + 1]);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return true;
        }),
        child: _pageView=PageView(
          ....
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Could you please add some comments to the code explaining what each line is and/or remove your custom logic with the categories and subcategories. That would help others.

Comment: For my use case - this is much better solution then combination of `GestureDetector` and `PageView` with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` since that combination is also changing the feel of scrolling. With your solution I can easily detect scroll attempts on first and last page and keep the original feel!

Comment: At the end I decided to use `OverscrollNotification` instead of `OverscrollIndicatorNotification` since I can get the amount of over scroll in `<OverscrollNotification>.overscroll` . So I can react only on signification amount of overscroll, and ignore eventual user's accidental drag event.

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution
PageView:

```
PageView(
          controller: page_controller,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          pageSnapping: true,
          children: [
            infoSlide(),
            infoSlide(),
            Container(child: Center(child: Text("hello")),decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(9,28,56, 1)),),
            Container(child: Center(child: Text("ddssf")),decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),),
          ],
        )
```

and this is my NotificationListener with the PageView:

```
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
        onNotification: ((notification) {
          //
          //this will happen when im at 0 and scroll back
          //
          if(notification.leading){
            context.pop();
          }
          //
          //this will happen when im at the last page and scroll forward
          //
          else{
            context.pop();
          }
          return true;
        }),
        child: PageView(
          controller: page_controller,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          pageSnapping: true,
          children: [
            //Container(child: Center(child: Text("ddssf")),decoration: BoxDecoration(color:  Color.fromRGBO(9,28,56, 1)),),
            infoSlide(),
            infoSlide(),
            Container(child: Center(child: Text("hello")),decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(9,28,56, 1)),),
            Container(child: Center(child: Text("ddssf")),decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),),
            //Container(child: Center(child: Text("ddssf")),decoration: BoxDecoration(color:  Color.fromRGBO(9,28,56, 1)),),
          ],
        ),
      )
```